# Using a controller to return different views in a django app

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, model-view-controller

I want to return multiple views in my app according to the logic in a controller which is connected to the url resolver.

Here is some example code of the idea that I have .

```
class Project(Singleton):

    TYPE1, TYPE2 , TYPE3 = (0,1,2)

    def init(self,request, slug):
        self.pengine = ProjectEngine()
        self.pengine.init()
        self.request = request
        self.slug = slug
        ptype = pengine.getProjectType()
        return self.showProjectView(ptype)

    def showProjectView(self, projectType):
        if(projectType == TYPE1):
            return Type1View.as_view(self.request, self.slug)
        elif(projectType == TYPE2):
            return Type2View.as_view(self.request, self.slug)
        else:
            return Type3.as_view(self.request, self.slug)
```

Type1View for example extends from Djangos default TemplateView class. ProjectEngine is supposed to be the model class to get the data from.

The url resolver would then get the callable view from the init method, either using the Singleton idea that I have here, or using a class only method the same way as how a base View class is implemented.

I'm just not sure if I should be using the MVC pattern this way. The url resolver is supposed to resolve directly to the view class methods, and I want to send that data from the controller , using the model class to the view. How do I achieve this? 
Does the as_view method have a way to send data through to it? Or should I let go of Django's View class and make another View here that corresponds to the design.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Edited the question to explain the issue more clearly.

Comment: BTW the code is not proper python code. If you want to define class constructor you need to name your method `__init__` instead of `init`. Secondly, you are using `self` inside `init` method without declaring such variable. Your `init` is an instance method so it should have `self` as first argument (python provides reference to `self` as first arg).

Comment: Wasnt really supposed to be clear cut python code. And the init is not the constructor. Its just an initialisor which I named as such. Breaks conventions. But allowed in python. I see the argument about the self parameter. Edited it now.